# Contact form fails on Drupal 7 (using Goodnex theme): not send e-mail

Tags: forms, email, drupal, contacts

I'm developing website using Drupal 7 (with Goodnex theme) and I have a problem on contact form: when click in 'Send' nothing happend. I was monitoring requests and discover that Drupal 7 search for the mysite/php/contact-send.php file, but it doesn't exist...

The "Contact" and "Contact form blocks" modules are installed and configured.

What can I do to solve it? I tried to create that file, but I don't know certain what I have to put in there, or what I have to return.

Comment: Please do not add "solved" to your question title. If you figured out a solution of your own, please post it as an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/220538) by clicking the check mark in the left margin.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, with the same theme. When/if I solve it, I'll post a solution here.

Comment: Maybe switch to Webform module?
https://www.drupal.org/project/webform